# Cannot query the value of this provider because it has no value available

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I am trying to build an android project, but it is showing the following errors:

org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer$TaskCreationException: Could not create task ':app:generateLintModuleInfo'.
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.taskCreationException(DefaultTaskContainer.java:719)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.access$600(DefaultTaskContainer.java:77)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer$TaskCreatingProvider.domainObjectCreationException(DefaultTaskContainer.java:711)
at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection$AbstractDomainObjectCreatingProvider.tryCreate(DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.java:948)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer$TaskCreatingProvider.access$1401(DefaultTaskContainer.java:658)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer$TaskCreatingProvider$1.run(DefaultTaskContainer.java:684)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer$TaskCreatingProvider.tryCreate(DefaultTaskContainer.java:680)
at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection$AbstractDomainObjectCreatingProvider.calculateOwnValue(DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.java:929)
at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.getOrNull(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:93)
at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.findByName(DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.java:295)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.findByName(DefaultTaskContainer.java:562)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.findByName(DefaultTaskContainer.java:76)
at org.gradle.plugins.ide.internal.tooling.GradleProjectBuilder.tasks(GradleProjectBuilder.java:104)
at org.gradle.plugins.ide.internal.tooling.GradleProjectBuilder.buildHierarchy(GradleProjectBuilder.java:80)
at org.gradle.plugins.ide.internal.tooling.GradleProjectBuilder.buildHierarchy(GradleProjectBuilder.java:58)
at org.gradle.plugins.ide.internal.tooling.GradleProjectBuilder.buildAll(GradleProjectBuilder.java:52)
at org.gradle.plugins.ide.internal.tooling.IdeaModelBuilder.buildAll(IdeaModelBuilder.java:75)
at org.gradle.plugins.ide.internal.tooling.IdeaModelBuilder.buildAll(IdeaModelBuilder.java:57)
at org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.internal.DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry$BuildOperationWrappingToolingModelBuilder$1$1.create(DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry.java:148)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry.withMutableStateOfAllProjects(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:141)
at org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.internal.DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry$BuildOperationWrappingToolingModelBuilder$1.call(DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry.java:144)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
at org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.internal.DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry$BuildOperationWrappingToolingModelBuilder.buildAll(DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry.java:141)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.DefaultBuildController.getModel(DefaultBuildController.java:82)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.DefaultBuildController.getModel(DefaultBuildController.java:63)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.BuildControllerAdapter.getModel(BuildControllerAdapter.java:58)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.AbstractBuildController.getModel(AbstractBuildController.java:26)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:67)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:40)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.InternalBuildActionAdapter.execute(InternalBuildActionAdapter.java:53)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ResultBuildingListener.buildResult(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:116)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ResultBuildingListener.buildFinished(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:106)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor31.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$ListenerDetails.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:398)
at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$ListenerDetails.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:380)
at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:61)
at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$EventBroadcast$ListenerDispatch.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:368)
at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$EventBroadcast$ListenerDispatch.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:355)
at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:43)
at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:245)
at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:157)
at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:61)
at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:346)
at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:249)
at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:141)
at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.buildFinished(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.finishBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:195)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.finishBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:133)
at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.create(GradleBuildController.java:73)
at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.create(GradleBuildController.java:67)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:178)
at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:67)
at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.configure(GradleBuildController.java:61)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:57)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:63)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:67)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:49)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:87)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:33)
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:49)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:27)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:104)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:55)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:37)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:67)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:50)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:59)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:55)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:41)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:47)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:31)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.provider.MissingValueException: Cannot query the value of this provider because it has no value available.
at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.get(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:86)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.GlobalScope.lambda$getBootClasspath$6(GlobalScope.java:337)
at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.DefaultProvider.calculateOwnValue(DefaultProvider.java:66)
at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.get(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:84)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.lint.LintModelModuleWriterTask$CreationAction.configure(LintModelModuleWriterTask.kt:417)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.lint.LintModelModuleWriterTask$CreationAction.configure(LintModelModuleWriterTask.kt:371)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.factory.TaskConfigurationActions.execute(TaskFactoryUtils.kt:94)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.factory.TaskConfigurationActions.execute(TaskFactoryUtils.kt:80)
at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultMutationGuard$2.execute(DefaultMutationGuard.java:44)
at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultMutationGuard$2.execute(DefaultMutationGuard.java:44)
at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext$CurrentApplication$1.execute(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:100)
at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction$1.run(DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator.java:95)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction.execute(DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator.java:92)
at org.gradle.internal.ImmutableActionSet$SetWithManyActions.execute(ImmutableActionSet.java:329)
at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.doAdd(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:264)
at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.doAdd(DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.java:113)
at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.add(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:258)
at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection$AbstractDomainObjectCreatingProvider.tryCreate(DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.java:944)
... 148 more

Please help me to solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

I solved above issue by upgrading my android studio 3.1 to latest version "Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1" available on https://developer.android.com/studio